# Downloading file using certutil and Python

Tags: python, cmd

I'm trying to download file by calling cmd command through Python. When I run this command in cmd:

```
certutil -urlcache -split -f https://www.contextures.com/SampleData.zip c:\temp\test.zip
```

The file downloads without any issues, but when I run that command through Python, the file is not being downloaded. I tried:

```
import subprocess
command = "certutil -urlcache -split -f https://www.contextures.com/SampleData.zip c:\temp\test.zip"

subprocess.Popen([command])
subprocess.call(command, shell=True)
```

also:

```
os.system(command)
```

Any ideas why this doesn't work? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: `Popen` (and when you don't use `shell=True`) may need list like `["certutil", "-urlcache", "-split", "-f", "https://www.contextures.com/SampleData.zip", "c:\temp\test.zip"]`

Comment: problem can makes also `\t` which has special meaning in Python string and you should use `"c:\\temp\\test.zip"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First: problem can makes `\t` which has special meaning in Python (and other languages) and you should use `"c:\\temp\\test.zip"` or you would have to use prefix `r` to create raw string `r"c:\temp\test.zip"`

Second: when you don't use `shell=True` then you need list like

```
["certutil", "-urlcache", "-split", "-f", "https://www.contextures.com/SampleData.zip", "c:\\temp\\test.zip"]
```

Sometimes people simply use `split(' ')` to create it

```
"certutil -urlcache -split -f https://www.contextures.com/SampleData.zip c:\\temp\\test.zip".split(" ")
```

And then you can test both versions

```
cmd = "certutil -urlcache -split -f https://www.contextures.com/SampleData.zip c:\\temp\\test.zip"

Popen(cmd.split(' '))

Popen(cmd, shell=True)
```

---

**EDIT:**

If you will have more complex command - ie. with `" "` inside string - then you can use standard module [shlex](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shlex.html) and command `shlex.split(cmd)`. To keep `\\` in path you may need `posix=False

```
import shlex

cmd = "certutil -urlcache -split -f https://www.contextures.com/SampleData.zip c:\\temp\\test.zip"

Popen(shlex.split(cmd, posix=False))
```

---

For example this gives incorrect list with 4 elements

```
'--text "hello world" --other'.split(' ')

['--text', '"hello', 'world"', '--other']
```

but this gives correct list with 3 elements

```
shlex.split('--text "hello world" --other')

['--text', 'hello world', '--other']
```

Answer (score 0):

Also, a `raw` string can be specified that will not interpret escape sequences such as `\t`.

```
Python 3.8.4 (tags/v3.8.4:dfa645a, Jul 13 2020, 16:46:45) [MSC v.1924 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> print("now\time")
now     ime
>>> print(r"now\time")
now\time
>>> print('now\time')
now     ime
>>> print(r'now\time')
now\time
```